# Responsive Bootstrap - changing number of divs per row from desktop to mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

New to responsive bootstrap here. I have 2 div's per row and 2 rows showing on my desktop. I used display: inline-block (see below link):

https://jsfiddle.net/9ya7kb67/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> content </div>
    <div class="child"> content </div>
    <div class="child"> content </div>
    <div class="child"> content </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 200px;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
```

However, I'd like to keep this layout in desktop but change it to 1 div per row (for 4 rows) on mobile using responsive bootstrap. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the bootstrap documentation for its grid system here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

There are 4 different types of classes `col-sm col-xs col-md col-lg` each one fitted for different screen sizes and you can combine them to make dynamic grids for your site.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Test col</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Test col</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Test col</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Test col</div>
</div>
```

I didn't exactly understand what your end goal is, but the code above is something similar to what you want. On small screens `col-xs-12` will fill the entire row, on medium to large screen you will have two `col-md-6` on each row. Make sure to read the bootstrap documentation to learn more about it.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but `col-md-6` still yields only 1 div per row. Does it matter that I set a width on the parent container and display:inline-block on the child elements?

Comment: Yes, the css you put interferes with the bootstrap css.